# EXTJS 7.2.0 CLASSIC - GRID HEADER INSERT ISSUE/BUG WITH CHROME 81

Tags: extjs, extjs7

Please see code example and attached fiddle.

Issue:
Basically, since Chrome 81 and maybe even before users of our application have reported an issue with the Ext.grid.Panel getHeaderContainer().insert not working. Basically, we have some dynamic columns that get set when a user changes selections in a combobox.

Question:
Does anyone know of a possible workaround for this issue? Or know if Sencha is aware of the problem and working on a fix?

Workaround:
Found that `grid.columns.length` is no longer returning 0 after removeAll()

```
header.insert(0, cols) works
header.add(cols) also works
```

ExtJS 7.2.0
Chrome 81 (No longer works)
Firefox 76.0.1 (Works)
Edge (Non-chromium) (Works)

Sencha Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/35vb

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Change Fields',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            handler: function(button, e) {

                var grid = Ext.getCmp('testGrid');
                console.log('grid = ', grid);

                var header = grid.getHeaderContainer();
                console.log('header Before = ', header);

               //Setup the columns for Grading Period = Semester
                var cols = [{ text: 'Student ID', dataIndex: 'StudentID'},
                    { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'LastFirst', width: 180},
                    { text: '1st Midterm Grade', dataIndex: 'GradEntA_1', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '1st Nine Weeks', dataIndex: 'GradEntA_2', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '2nd Midterm Grade', dataIndex: 'GradEntA_3', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '2nd Nine Weeks', dataIndex: 'GradEntA_4', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '1st Exam Value', dataIndex: 'GradEntB_1', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '1st Semester Value', dataIndex: 'GradEntB_2', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '1st Semester Credit', dataIndex: 'GradEntB_3', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '3rd Midterm Grade', dataIndex: 'GradEntC_1', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '3rd Nine Weeks', dataIndex: 'GradEntC_2', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '4th Midterm Grade', dataIndex: 'GradEntC_3', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '4th Nine Weeks', dataIndex: 'GradEntC_4', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '2nd Exam Value', dataIndex: 'GradEntD_1', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '2nd Semester Value', dataIndex: 'GradEntD_2', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: '2nd Semester Credit', dataIndex: 'GradEntD_3', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'},
                    { text: 'Final for Term', dataIndex: 'GradFinal', width: 140, editor: 'textfield'}
                   ];

                header.removeAll();
                header.insert(cols);

                console.log('header After = ', header);


            }
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Column Demo',
            id: 'testGrid',
            width: '100%',
            columns: [
                {text: 'First Name',  dataIndex:'firstname'},
                {text: 'Last Name',  dataIndex:'lastname'},
                {text: 'Hired Month',  dataIndex:'hired', xtype:'datecolumn', format:'M'},
                {text: 'Department (Yrs)', xtype:'templatecolumn', tpl:'{dep} ({seniority})'}
            ],
            forceFit: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });


    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [grid reconfigure](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure) function instead to avoid problems.

Ex.

```
tree.reconfigure(store);
// or
grid.reconfigure(columns);
// or
tree.reconfigure(null, columns);
```

Comment: The ```grid.reconfigure(store)``` happens in a combo change event. The column change happens in another function, called after the reconfigure. I could've passed in the store into the function and called reconfigure, yes. But  ```grid.getHeaderContainer()``` is a documented/supported method for modifying the grid headers as well. Not sure why you -1 my approach?

Comment: Did you tried to use `header.updateLayout()` after insert? I don't see any problems there in Chrome 81.0. ps. I didn't give a minus.

Comment: The issue I found turned out to be in the ```grid.columns.length``` property not always being defined. ```updateLayout()``` appears to be in the event stack of the ```header.insert()``` and ```header.add()``` methods so it wasn't needed. Everything works fine now using the add() method.